# PHP mess detector optional parameters

Tags: php, annotations, optional-parameters, code-standards, phpmd

I have interface X

```
interface X
{
    public function foo($x, $y = 0);
}
```

then I have class

```
class xx implements X
{
    public function foo($x, $y = 0)
    {
        // use $x, but not $y
    }
}
```

This is perfectly normal, because I do not want to use optional `$y` in this implementation of `X`. But PMD yells that $y is unused parameter.

What can I do to easily change PMD behaviour? Only solution that I found was to suppress the warning with `@SuppressWarnings(unused)` annotation, bet thats not what I really like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{@inheritdoc}`, which was introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/phpmd/phpmd/commit/d033354f43bfac5b06146c20cb2ef0aff9196ada#src/main/php/PHP/PMD/Rule/UnusedFormalParameter.php) to skip the check for implemented methods. to this day i guess this is the only solution to this problem.

Just add this as DocBlock for the implemented method

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
```